# How to check system's time format in chrome - 12 hours or 24 hours in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`date.toLocaleTimeString` does not work in chrome and always return time in 12 hours format. I need to display time on the basis of system's time format.

Comment: Checking the system's time format might be a tedious approach, I'd rather use the `getTime()` to get the time stamp and display the time from that

Comment: There is no ECMAScript interface to determine system settings such as the user system preferences for time formats and the format of *toString* and *toLocaleString* are entirely implementation dependent. So what you are asking is impossible to achieve reliably across even the most popular implementations.

Comment: @Laazo—not so much tedious as impossible using ECMAScript alone.

Comment: you might want to throw moment-timezone into play and determine common 12/24 settings based on timezone. thats probably the best aproach unless you ask the user.

Comment: I think that the title differ from the content of the question, I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you want to display time in different locales (and you can use external library) have a look to [i18n](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) section of momentjs docs, maybe you are looking for [`format('LT')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Note that you have to _tell_ moment which locale you want to use.

Comment: Its time format and not Locale. So, need to know current system (12/24 hour) format.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **No** you can't get the default time format in the browser, because it relies on the System and on the browser settings, thought JavaScript doesn't have access for such options.

But if you want to manage the time format within your code, you can specify the format by which you wnat to show your Date.

Actually the [**toLocaleString()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) have a boolean `hour12` option that tells the engine to use or not the `12 hours` format:

```
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour12: false }));
```

If you set it to  `false` it will display the time in `24 hours` format.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var x = date() 

// Tue May 15 2012 05:45:40 GMT-0500
```

They already provide you the datetime with the timezone

OR

To make your life easier, use this

```
 https://momentjs.com/
```

Comment: User can alter the time format in any Locale. i.e. We can have a time format as 24 hours in US locale. so, need to determine the current system settings.

Comment: the locale data cannot be set by the browser / javascript. It needs to be set by the server, and when you create / update date Objects through CRUD in the front-end, it must already have the UTC data probably as one hidden input HTML tag.

Comment: so the design of the flow needs to be changed.

Comment: the locale data cannot be set by the browser / javascript. --Not required. Need to perform read operation.